# How to Access styles from React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, attributes

I am trying to access the width and height styles of a div in React but I have been running into one problem. This is what I got so far:

```
componentDidMount()  {
  console.log(this.refs.container.style);     
}


render()  {
   return (
      <div ref={"container"} className={"container"}></div>  //set reff
   );
}
```

This works but the output that I get is a CSSStyleDeclaration object and in the all property I can all the CSS selectors for that object but they none of them are set. They are all set to an empty string.

This is the output of the CSSStyleDecleration is: http://pastebin.com/wXRPxz5p

Any help on getting to see the actual styles (event inherrited ones) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.container)` instead

Comment: OMG YES!! That worked perfectly... Is this commonly used? Cause Iv'e never seen it before on the React Docs

EDIT: Can you please make an answer so I can accept it 8)

Comment: It is not React function, and it is possible not working in old IE (<=8). @Vikramaditya offered better solution.

Comment: I tried this and get `Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For React v <= 15

```
console.log( ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container).style); //React v > 0.14

console.log( React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container).style);//React v <= 0.13.3
```

EDIT:

> For getting the specific style value

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container)).getPropertyValue("border-radius"));// border-radius can be replaced with any other style attributes;
```

> For React v>= 16

assign ref using callback style or by using `useRef/createRef`.

```
assignRef = element => {
  this.container = element;
}
getStyle = () => {
  
  const styles = this.container.style;
  console.log(styles);
  // for getting computed styles
  const computed = window.getComputedStyle(this.container).getPropertyValue("border-radius"));// border-radius can be replaced with any other style attributes;
  console.log(computed);
}
```

Comment: Is `React.findDOMNode` [deprecated](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678)?

Comment: yes, `React.findDOMNode` was there till react 0.13.3. Now use `ReactDOM` for all DOM related operations.

Comment: I think what Dan Abramov is saying in [the Github issue I linked](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678) is that the method will be deprecated, whether from either `React.findDOMNode` or `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`.  From [the documentation on `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode): "findDOMNode is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM node. In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because it pierces the component abstraction."  Dan recommends using `ref` instead.

Comment: Add'l information on the deprecation of `findDOMNode`: [it doesn't work with the Jest test renderer (but refs do)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7371#issuecomment-260946944) (Dan Abramov: "There are no plans to support findDOMNode() in test renderer because it should be agnostic of React DOM and there is no way to implement it in a way that won't break in the future.")

Comment: findDOMNode is deprecated. i have update the answer @CyberJunkie.

Comment: For React v>=16, How do you use assignRef()? When I implement this I get "TypeError: this.container is undefined". I tried making a ref to container in the constructor as `this.container = React.createRef();` then tried calling it in my class component as `<button onClick={()=>this.getStyle()} ref={this.container}>test</button>` but then get a different "TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element."

Comment: what is the "this.container" ?

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example of computing the CSS property value via **React Refs** and `.getComputedStyle` method:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.divRef = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const styles = getComputedStyle(this.divRef.current)

        console.log(styles.color) // rgb(0, 0, 0)
        console.log(styles.width) // 976px
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.divRef}>Some Text</div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of function components use the useRef Hook:

```
const _optionsButton = useRef(null);
const _onSelectText = (event) => {
  if (true) {
    _optionsButton.current.style["display"] = "block";
  } else {
    _optionsButton.current.style["display"] = "none";
  }
  console.log(_optionsButton.current.style); //all styles applied to element
};
```

add ref attribute to component

```
<IconButton
  style={{
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
    fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
    border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
    position: "absolute",
    display: "none",
  }}
  color="primary"
  component="span"
  onClick={() => {}}
  ref={_optionsButton} //this
>
  Check
</IconButton>;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that while ReactDOM.findDOMNode is usable today, it will be deprecated in the future in place of callback refs.

There is a post [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220) by Dan Abramov which outlines reasons for not using findDOMNode while providing examples of how to replace the use of ReactDOM.findDOMNode with callback refs.

Since I've seen SO users get upset when only a link was included in an answer, so I will pass along one of the examples Dan has kindly provided:

## findDOMNode(stringDOMRef)

```
**Before:**

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    findDOMNode(this.refs.something).scrollIntoView();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref='something' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
**After:**

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.something.scrollIntoView();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={node => this.something = node} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops! I just noticed that this was already mentioned in the comments below the accepted answer. :P

Comment: And for what it's worth, using refs is even easier now if you're working with a functional component and the useRef() hook! (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` method and work from there. Here's the code that does what you need.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

componentDidMount: function() {
  var elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container);
  console.log(elem.offsetWidth, elem.offsetHeight);    
},

render: function() {
   return (
      <div ref={"container"} className={"container"}>
        Hello world
      </div>
   );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29966/)

Answer (score -1):

You already get the style, the reason why CSSStyleDeclaration object's props have so much empty string value is it's link to the inner style.

See what will happen if you make change like below:

`<div ref={"container"} className={"container"} style={{ width: 100 }}></div>`