# How to get height of a div in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to get height of a parent div using React JS.

The html structure is as follows :

```
<div ref="sectionSlider">
   <div class="detailsOutterDiv">
      <div class="swiper" style="width: 100%;">
         <div class="detailsInnerDiv">
              <div class="slide">
                 <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;">
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;">
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="slider-thumbnails">
         <div class="thumb">
             <img src="someURl">
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the css-scss structure is like this :

```
.detailsOutterDiv{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.detailsInnerDiv{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px;
  width: 10000%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.slide{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.slide img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


.slider-thumbnails{
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: $primary-margin-xs - 5;
  text-align: center;

  .thumb{
    display: inline-block;
    width: (100% / 12);

    img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0 2px;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the height of the div with `ref="sectionSlider"`.

I tried to do this on a few ways in `componentDidMount` like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
    //First way
    let top = this.refs["sectionSlider"].offsetHeight; 

    //Second way
    let top = this.refs["sectionSlider"].clientHeight; 

    //Third way
    let top = this.refs["sectionSlider"].getBoundingClientRect().height;

    //Fourth way
    let node = this.refs["sectionSlider"];
    let nodeStyle = window.getComputedStyle(node);
    let top = parseInt(nodeStyle.getPropertyValue('height').replace(/\D/g,''));
}
```

And in every case `top` is 82 what is not true.

It looks like :

[image]

Thus, the div has height of 523.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/nkbt/react-height?

Comment: @fahrradflucht I would like to do it without external components.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean that you should add this as a dependency, but look up how it is done there...

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170581/how-to-access-styles-from-react/35170938

Comment: Where even is the div with `ref="slider"` I can't find it in your code.

Comment: @Teedub No.I tried it, but I still get 82. I think that the problem is in the photos. They have height of 0. For some reason `componentDidUpdate` fires before all photos are loaded.

Comment: @fahrradflucht It's div with ref `sectionSlider` . My mistake.

Comment: @Boky Well it would be kinda dirty but you could load the images with js and pass them down as props. Then you measure the height in `componentDidUpdate`...

Comment: They are already loaded with react. `{this.props.photos.map((p, i) => <div key={i} className="slide"><img src={p.image_url} onClick={this.openPopup.bind(this, p.image_url)} style={{backgroundColor:"black"}} /></div>)}`

Comment: Did you try something like this: `<img src="smileyface.jpg" onLoad={() => { console.log(this.refs["sectionSlider"].clientHeight) }} />` ? - In your case you would obviously do this with a middleman to make sure `onLoad` got called for all images.

Comment: @fahrradflucht Yes. And then I get the height of the image but I have other sections on the page and I need the height of all of them. That it's why I tried to do it in componentDidMount.

Comment: Well then call a method on the component in `onLoad`

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is (according to your guess) that the images aren't loaded you could do something like this:

```
const Example = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      imagesLoaded: 0,
    };
  },

  printClientHeight() {
    console.log(this.wrapper.clientHeight)
  },

  updateLoadedImages() {
    this.setState({ imagesLoaded: this.state.imagesLoaded + 1 })
    if (this.state.imagesLoaded = 4) {
      printClientHeight();
    }
  },

  setWrapperRef(el) {
    this.wrapper = el;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
        <div className="detailsOutterDiv">
          <div className="swiper" style="width: 100%;">
            <div className="detailsInnerDiv">
              <div className="slide">
                <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;" onLoad={updateLoadedImages}/ >
              </div>
              <div className="slide">
                <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;"  onLoad={updateLoadedImages}/>
              </div>
              <div className="slide">
                <img src="someURl" style="background-color: black;"  onLoad={updateLoadedImages}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slider-thumbnails">
          <div className="thumb">
            <img src="someURl"  onLoad={updateLoadedImages}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Obviously you could clean this up quite a bit by getting the image tag count dynamically but I think you get the point...