# How to get React Native element's style values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Hook.
How to get the borderRadius or backgroundColor of a component(with useRef())?
We can get position with `measure` method.
But how to get other style properties, e.g borderRadius, backgroundColor, in React Native??

Comment: Does this help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170581/how-to-access-styles-from-react ?

Comment: @Mike It only works in React (getComputedStyle can do it), but not in React Native??