# React's element node doesn't have css properties when declared with css modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, dom-events

when I use the CSS modules to style the react element, then I'm unable to fetch the style of the node. All styles in that node are empty strings. How to access the style of a node in this case.

```
<div className={collapseTitle} onClick={collapseCard}>Caard</div>

const collapseCard =(e) => {
        console.log(e.target.style.maxHeight)
}
```

CSS file

```
.collapseTitle {
   max-height: 10px
}
```

Comment: I used scrollHeight to get the data anyway but I just wanted to know why empty strings are assigned to style even though it has a value

Comment: similar question is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170581/how-to-access-styles-from-react/35170938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code below.

```
import React,{useRef} from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    
    export default function App() {
       const divRef =useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
       const collapseCard =(e:any) => {
        console.log(e.target.style.maxHeight)
        const styles = getComputedStyle(divRef.current!)
        console.log(styles);
        console.log(styles.textAlign);
      }
      return (
        <div className="App" ref={divRef} onClick={collapseCard}>
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Solution2:- using Ref in the loop

```
const arrLength = arr.length;
  const [elRefs, setElRefs] = React.useState([]);
 const collapseCard =(e:any,divRef:any) => {
    console.log(e.target.style.maxHeight)
    const styles = getComputedStyle(divRef.current!)
    console.log(styles);
    console.log(styles.textAlign);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // add or remove refs
    setElRefs(elRefs => (
      Array(arrLength).fill().map((_, i) => elRefs[i] || createRef())
    ));
  }, [arrLength]);

  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map((el, i) => (
        <div className="App" ref={elRefs[i]} onClick={()=>collapseCard(elRefs[i])}>...</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: collapse title div will be in a for each loop so I cant define a ref for all the values in it

Comment: I added a solution for your use case