# CSSStyleDeclaration not giving any value while using useRef in react

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, line-height

I want to get the line-height of the element in Rect after render and for this I'm using useRef

```
const titleLineHeight = titletext.current?.style.lineHeight;
```

and I didn't get any value in `CSSStyleDeclaration`

[image]

Im not sure how to get the values. Please help me

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access styles from React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170581/how-to-access-styles-from-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getComputedStyle()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```
const paraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const paraStyle = paraRef.current && getComputedStyle(paraRef.current);
    console.log(paraStyle.lineHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p ref={paraRef}>New text</p>
    </div>
  );
```